# ajax call only once on first time click of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am designing a chatting application just like WhatsApp web . in that right now I have dummy data for chats. so suppose, if I click on any chat then corresponding chat logs are displayed but these chat logs are dummy data. same way I have done for other chats also but now what I want is if I click on any of the chat then an ajax call should happen and chat logs are rendered and displayed dynamically but this ajax call should happen only one for every chat that means if I click for first time on some chat an ajax call should happen but if click the second time no ajax call should happen.
any suggestions..?

Comment: you know that your question is extreme low quality, right?

Comment: [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one). Did you even look for it?

Comment: @se0ng11 no I don't think so. I have explained according to my need but I want a generic suggestion .

Comment: Dude you're going to have to add some code to this question. But it sounds like you could destroy the "click" event listener attached to the html element after it's clicked once. There should be some jQuery function that does that.  http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: but there are more functionalities attached to the click event . so destroying click event might affect other functionalities.

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to get a bit creative and call a function on first invocation that detaches the event listener then adds it again but this time with the functionality that you do want. Or you could try to learn to use vue.js, then you won't have issues like this

Comment: Yes @Se0ng11, This question is low quality. If he does little bit R&D on it. I am sure he gets the answer.

Comment: @AvanishKumar Dude I have explained properly what I want so if you are not getting it . icant help and as per now I done coding for this so I cant share any code also to make you understand. BTW thanks fo your beautiful suggestion.

Comment: @nishantsingh, please check my answer and ask if any doubts regarding it.

Comment: @nishantsingh We understand your problem. We are saying first do R&D on it if you can't find your answer then ask a question. Lots of answers available on cloud related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** I understood that, once you click on a chat and got data, from the next time ajax call should not be made which will be an extra call.

**Solution:** The solution for your question will be, first time when you get response from the server, save it in `localStorage`, A `localStorage` is a powerful feature of browser which stores data in the browser session.

**Implemenatation:**

An example api call,

```
$.post(
    "chat-api-url",
    { chat: "chatId" },
    function(data) {
        localStorage.setItem('chatId', 'data')
    }
);
```

So, now after click in jquery check condition,

```
if(localStorage.getItem('chatId') == undefined)
{
    $.post(
    "chat-api-url",
    { chat: "chatId" },
        function(data) {
            localStorage.setItem('chatId', data)
            this.chatData = data;
        }
    );
} else{
    this.chatData = localStorage.getItem('chatId');
}
```

PS:

`localStorage.setItem` stores into localstorage

`localStorage.getItem` retrieves from. localstorage

[**Here is a documeantation regarding different storages**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: somewhat I got what you have tried to explain . it can be on of the approaches but can you explain me your code once again in detail so that I can ask further questions on this if i have while implementation.

Comment: once you click on a chat, you will get the chat response, then store that response in localstorage.. then when u click again, check if data for specific chat is already fetched( using localstorage), if already fetched dont make api call, if not make an api call.

Comment: okay nice. Iwill implement and see if it really works. but according to the explanation which you have given is that's what I want ot happen in my application. lets see if it really works. thanks for your answer.